# Right middle x and y position of button

Tags: android

I want to find right middle position of button in android. I have second button on other hand.I will find x and y position of both and will draw path between them so they look connected.

[This position i wanted of button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nE0Ep.png)

Comment: You know the origin of the button, which is the top-left corner.  The X coordinate is the origin.X + (buttonWidth).  The Y coordinate is the origin.Y + ( buttonHeight / 2)

Comment: Actually I have many button like this and I want to draw paths between them..I can try this but is there any other way to use without origin

Comment: How are you positioning the buttons? Are you using their translationX/Y? What type of container are the buttons in?

Comment: Adding what code you have already will greatly help everyone understand how to solve your problem (code + layouts + what you've tried already).

Comment: Buttons are positing in linear vertical layout in both side of frame layout

Comment: I posted layout and in java code I cant find any way to draw line yet.After getting position I cant draw

Comment: Instead of get center point. I try to draw path using right end position of first button and top left position of second button

Comment: Why have you just rolled back your Question to Revision 1 @KrishnaJ ?

Comment: It is not useful for others in future